# Disabling or Forcing Spark Hash Partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, databricks

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize some Databricks joins. Below is the setup:

- Four tables in a star schema

  - Huge fact, **purchases**, (~3 billion rows) containing purchases over time by pet (cat and dog only) and by owner
  - Large **owner** dimension (~500 million rows)
  - Large **dog** dimension (~1 billion rows) containing info about the dog for which the purchase was made
  - Large **cat** dimension (~1 billion rows) containing info about the cat for which the purchase was made
- **purchases** left joins to each of **owner**, **dog**, and **cat** on *Owner ID*, *Dog ID*, and *Cat ID*, respectively

The issue is that I want to avoid reshuffling the fact table when I join to all three tables in a single query. Plus, the dog/cat shuffles are skewed, since a transaction is either for a dog or cat, but not both.

**PROPOSAL**

Since each pet belongs to a single owner, each table can or does contain the *Owner ID*. I'd like to write the data for all four tables into Azure Data Lake so that they are bucketed and sorted by *Owner ID*. The goal would be to bypass the Exchange step of the physical plan when joining the four tables.

The **purchases** to **owner** join would clearly benefit from this strategy. In theory, this strategy would also colocate all the dog/cat dimensional data with the relevant fact data. However, I worry that joining **purchases** to **dog** on *Dog ID* would force a reshuffle by *Dog ID*. Same argument for cats.

Can I prohibit Spark from reshuffling by *Cat ID* / *Dog ID* and force it to preserve the *Owner ID* bucketing? It sounds dangerous for an arbitrary join, but it could make sense for this use case.

Any other thoughts on how to handle these joins?

**CAVEATS**

- Assume that the **dog** and **cat** tables are different enough that unioning them into a single **pet** table is not allowed.
- I'm simplifying my real data content to make the scenario easier for anyone to relate to.

Comment: If you were to force the `owner_id` hash, the only way to join `cat` and `dog` table would be to literally stream (broadcast) all of the data of those tables into each of the worker/partition. Is there a reason you wish to avoid a shuffle beyond the cost? Have you tried optimizing the number of shuffle partitions etc?

Comment: Do you have an owner/dog and owner/cat relationship anywhere? You could use it to pre-join dog/cat with the owner table

Comment: Right, just want to avoid shuffle for the cost, and haven't optimized shuffle partitions.

Comment: Yes, I could create an owner/dog relationship, then bucket the fact and owner/dog pre-joined table by _Dog ID_. I worry about skew though (since dogs are ~50% of the fact records) and I'll still have to reshuffle for the owner/cat join. Same argument for creating an owner/cat join...

Comment: You could union `cat` and `dog` and have a computed column `animal_id`. attach the `owner` to that newly created table and then join it with `purchases` on `[owner_id, animal_id]`